# Ansible can't resolve host name error

Tags: ansible

Currently trying to run just a simple playbook on an Ansible install on Centos7, everything is up to date. I can run a simple raw module and specify the host but when I run the playbook I have get a "cannot resolve host name"

Here are the logs

```
[root@ohnetwork01 playbooks]# ansible-playbook -vvvvvv -u user.user -k version_playbook.yaml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:
Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0
PLAYBOOK: version_playbook.yaml ************************************************
1 plays in version_playbook.yaml
PLAY [Get version] *************************************************************
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
<192.168.1.34> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.168.1.34> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-264756931089857 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-264756931089857="` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-264756931089857 `" ) && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.33> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.168.1.33> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-152708795243660 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-152708795243660="` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-152708795243660 `" ) && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.34> PUT /tmp/tmpymgKXv TO /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-264756931089857/setup
<192.168.1.34> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-264756931089857/setup; rm -rf "/tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-264756931089857/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.33> PUT /tmp/tmpW5FEgv TO /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-152708795243660/setup
<192.168.1.33> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-152708795243660/setup; rm -rf "/tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529280.8-152708795243660/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [P-9396PXb.domain.local]
ok: [P-9396PXa.domain.local]
TASK [nxos_facts] **************************************************************
task path: /home/user/playbooks/version_playbook.yaml:8
<192.168.1.33> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.168.1.33> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-258697976681834 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-258697976681834="` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-258697976681834 `" ) && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.34> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.168.1.34> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-135897636845763 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-135897636845763="` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-135897636845763 `" ) && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.33> PUT /tmp/tmpvaaDMQ TO /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-258697976681834/nxos_facts
<192.168.1.33> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-258697976681834/nxos_facts; rm -rf "/tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-258697976681834/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.34> PUT /tmp/tmpK7TYAS TO /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-135897636845763/nxos_facts
<192.168.1.34> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-135897636845763/nxos_facts; rm -rf "/tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466529281.26-135897636845763/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [P-9396PXa.domain.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"host": "", "password": null, "port": null, "provider": null, "ssh_keyfile": null, "transport": "cli", "use_ssl": false, "username": null, "validate_certs": true}, "module_name": "nxos_facts"}, "msg": "failed to connect to :22 - unable to resolve host name"}
fatal: [P-9396PXb.domain.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"host": "", "password": null, "port": null, "provider": null, "ssh_keyfile": null, "transport": "cli", "use_ssl": false, "username": null, "validate_certs": true}, "module_name": "nxos_facts"}, "msg": "failed to connect to :22 - unable to resolve host name"}
NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @version_playbook.retry
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
P-9396PXa.domain.local : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
P-9396PXb.domain.local : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

and here's the host file and playbook I'm using, insanely simple as I was just trying to test

```
#### Host entry ####
[ProdCoreSwitches]
P-9396PXa.domain.local ansible_host=192.168.1.33
P-9396PXb.domain.local ansible_host=192.168.1.34
#### Playbook ####
---
- name: Get version
  connection: local
  hosts: ProdCoreSwitches
  tasks:
    - nxos_facts:
        host= "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Anything I should be changing?

Edit: After changing the connection from local I get the following:

```
fatal: [P-9396PXa.domain.local]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the remote directory. Consider changing the remote temp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466538148.97-100745005340782 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1466538148.97-100745005340782=\"` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466538148.97-100745005340782 `\" ), exited with result 16: Syntax error while parsing '/bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466538148.97-100745005340782 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1466538148.97-100745005340782=\"` echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1466538148.97-100745005340782 `\" ) && sleep 0''\n\n\nCmd exec error.\n", "unreachable": true}
```

Comment: You have a `connection: local` despite apparently attempting a remote connection. That jumps out at me first.

Comment: I'll change it back, that was initially for troubleshooting and let you knw

Comment: That was partially the issue it appears it's trying to make a remote directory these being network devices I don't think it's possible... Sorry I'm new to this and have been struggling.

Comment: There is a typo – remove space after `host=` – so the host parameter is actually empty in your playbook. Generally people use `param=value` in one-line syntax, and `param: value` in multiline. So you can change `=` with `:` and that will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the content of task "nxos_facts"? Also where did you define "{{ inventory_hostname }}" and what's the value(s)?